# What datatype to use for return of Interface using generics?

Tags: java

With this interface:

```
interface SomeInterface<E> {
  List<E> getList();
}
```

And this implementation:

```
private void someMethod(SomeInterface someImplementation) {
  Object item = someImplementation.getList().get(0);  // here
}
```

What would be the appropriate datatype to use?  Just `Object`, as shown?

Comment: Can't you make `someMethod` generic too?

Comment: Since you are using raw types only Object is acceptable here (without explicit casting). If you would  use `SomeInterface<T>` then you could store result of `get()` in reference of `T` type.

Comment: Appropriate for what? What do you plan to do with `item`?

Comment: You created generic BUT you didnot use generic in someMethod????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private <T> void someMethod(SomeInterface<T> someImplementation) {
  T item = someImplementation.getList().get(0);  // here
}
```

`Object` is fine too, as long as you don't need to do something like `someImplementation.getList().add(item)` later. The key to this example is that it avoids the use of a raw type, so that the compiler can ensure that you've written type-safe code.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to avoid the use of raw types is to use a wildcard `?` in the signature. If you did it that way the appropriate type for `item` *would* be `Object`:

```
private void someMethod(SomeInterface<?> someImplementation) {
    Object item = someImplementation.getList().get(0);  
}
```

The downside of doing it this way is that you cannot use the generic type `E` in the body of the method.